# How to write a real number

Tags: fortran

I need a simple fortran program that writes a real number.

The code is the following one:

`program main

```
REAL :: A
A=342.3

Write (*,'(F3.1)') , A
```

end program main`

The output i get in vscode is ***

If I use A=3 and I1 instead of F3.1, I get the expected value of 3.

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you think `F3.1` means? `***` is the correct output in this case, but to explain why it would be helpful for us to know where your misunderstanding sits.

Comment: As the linked question shows, the `3` in `F3.1` says the width should be 3, and the `.1` says with one decimal digit. `342.3` requires a width of 5 with one decimal digit. `F0.1` or `F5.1` would be better.

Comment: I already understood, I thought that F3.1 would give a float with 3 numbers in the left of the comma adn one decimal place. Thx and sorry for the bad question

Comment: This isn't a bad question.